# Can you find what I am?

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking, affix-riddle

Here's a simple affix-riddle .

> My prefix is the sound of an animal. 
> My infix, the missing of the cast. 
> My suffix, what children like to hear. 
> My whole, deals with the past.

Can you guess the word?

If it takes time to find the answer, hints will be provided.

Comment: Got to be honest, I'm not convinced by using 'the missing of the cast' as a clue here... That's very ambiguous and there are several better ways to clue what you needed to here - don't sacrifice quality for rhyming! In tandem with a misspelled prefix (the word usually has two S's) this doesn't make for the most satisfying riddle, sorry.

Comment: @Stiv ok I consider that as a suggestion, I wanted to make it a bit hard to figure the answer out but I think I found no other way to do so. Also can't Hiss be considered as His? I really didn't expect that to be a lot misspelled.

Comment: Thank you for interacting with feedback :) Riffing an alternative example from a couple of minutes' thought, you could rhyme (e.g.): "My infix is [a rocky peak](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tor) / My whole of times long past does speak." This way the infix is clued pretty solidly and a rhyme scheme is maintained. Don't rush to publish - take your time to craft a truly great riddle :) (Don't change anything now though or it will invalidate the checkmarked answer.)

Comment: PS Re your other question: A snake's noise is typically spelled HISS in English - [HIS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/his) is the male possessive and not really a lot else... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> History

My prefix is the sound of an animal.

> His is the sound of a snake

My infix, the missing of the cast.

> Or to make the word CASTOR.

My suffix, what children like to hear.

> Story

My whole, deals with the past.

> History